# How to avoid hard coding URLS

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, .net-core, localhost

I'm hosting a .NET web api using IIS, the api features a password reset function which send the user to a reset password page, now im wondering how would could I avoid hardcoding the url

```
 private ReturnHandler SendResetPasswordMail(string email, string ott)
    {
        ReturnHandler result = new ReturnHandler();
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        emails.Add(email);
        string subject = "Promjena lozinke";
        string link = "http://axatszg-vw0038:13702/#/change-password";
        string[] parameters = { subject, "link za promjenu lozinke:", link + "?token="  + ott};
```

basically instead of fixating "axatszg-vw0038:13702" or "localhost:13702" could I somehow have my code access the host

Comment: put it in configuration file and read it from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Web.config you can put your value in `appSettings tag`, like:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="url" value="yourURL" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can get it as follows:

```
string link=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
```

in `.netCore` you can define the variable in the `appsettings.json` as follows:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
 "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
  },
  "myLinks": {
      "link1": "axatszg-vw0038:13702",
      "link2": "localhost:13702"
   }
}
```

and read this variables in `Controller` with `Dependency Injection`:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private string myLink1 { get; set; }
    private string myLink2 { get; set; }

    public TestController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
         this.myLink1 = configuration.GetValue<string> ("myLinks:link1");
         this.myLink2 = configuration.GetValue<string> ("myLinks:link2");
    }
}
```