# Application_Start event on ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How would I go about setting global variables in ASP.NET Core 6.0(razor pages)?

I have some information in the database, for example, ServiceName, ContactEmail and so on, and want to save it to my static class.

I don't want to access the database every time I need to display the information.
In addition, there aren't Global.asax in ASP.NET Core .

In ASP.NET MVC 5 (based on .net framework), I could do it like

```
// global.asax
protected void Application_Start() {
  var context = new DefaultConnection();
  MyConfig.ServiceName = context.GlobalSettings.SingleOrDefault().ServiceName;
  // MyConfig is my static class
}
```

But I don't know where I should do it in ASP.NET Core project.
How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: _"and want to save it to my static class."_ - static classes isn't generally how things in .NET Core work. Normally you'd have some kind of service, and inject options into it with dependency injection. See [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729997/how-to-avoid-hard-coding-urls/73731838#73731838

Comment: I have figure out necessity of using DI.
By the way, where should I get values from the database?
I want to hit the database only once when the application will start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lazy-loading is probably a very good choice for you.

**Step 1:**  Create a data service that provides your data.

```cs
public interface IStaticDbData // Think of a better name!
{
    public Task<string> GetContactEmailAsync();
    public Task<string> GetServiceNameAsync();
    // Etc.
}

public class StaticDbData : IStaticDbData
{
    // Since we want a singleton, we'll have to synchronize the data fetching.
    private object _lock = new object();
    private string _contactEmail;
    private string _serviceName;
    // Etc.

    // Try to create a single function that loads all of the data in one round trip to the DB.
    // This will run in its own thread, so the calling thread can be awaited.
    private Task LoadAllDataAsync()
        => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                //Re-check after locking.
                if (_contactEmail != null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                // Database code here to extract your data.
                // Save to the individual fields.
            }
        });

    public async Task<string> GetContactEmailAsync()
    {
        // See if data is there.
        if (_contactEmail != null)
        {
            return _contactEmail;
        }
        // Data was not there.  Load data.
        await LoadAllDataAsync();
        return _contactEmail;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetServiceNameAsync()
    {
        if (_serviceName != null)
        {
            return _serviceName;
        }
        await LoadAllDataAsync();
        return _serviceName;
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**  Now that you have your service interface and service implementation, register the m in the IoC container.  In **program.cs**:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IStaticDbData, StaticDbData>();
```

**Step 3:**  Consume the service as you would any other service.

```cs
public class SomeOtherServiceOrControllerOrWhatever
{
    private IStaticDbData StaticDbDataSvc { get; }
    // Constructor-injected.
    public SomeOtherServiceOrControllerOrWhatever(IStaticDbData staticDbDataSvc)
    {
        StaticDbDataSvc = staticDbDataSvc;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**  Make sure that your consuming services are also registered and resolved using the IoC container.

Comment: Hi, Jose.
I prefer the first way you indicated.
I'd like to know the method using singleton and lazy-loading.

I'm grateful to you.

Comment: @csharper There you go.  Did not test it, but hopefully works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

> This is sudo code

You can create a static class with static properties:

```
public static class MyConfig
{
    public static string Setting1 {set; get;}
    ...
}
```

then write a method to fetch data from your database and fill `MyConfig` and in the `Program.cs` file just call that method:

```
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
CallYourMethodHere(); <-----
```

another is you can do this:

first create a static class:

```
public static class MyConfig
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> MyConfigs {set; get;}
    
    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfigFromDatabase(bool forceToFill)
    {
        if(MyConfigs == null || MyConfigs.Any() == false || forceToFill == true)
        {
            //Fetch Data From Database and Fill MyConfig
        }
    }

    public static string GetConfig(string configName)
    {
        return GetConfigFromDatabase(false)[configName];
    }
}
```

In solution 2 you have to consider some thread-safe and race condition concepts.

Comment: Thanks Arian.
Sorry, I decided to not use static class due to everyone's oppose.
Although story changes, the codes after 'app.Run();' not work in my environment.
For example, code like this:

app.Run();
MyConfig.CompanyName = "ABC";

As a result, it seemed that MyConfig.CompanyName keeps empty in other page I confirmed.