# cannot read values for few keys from local.settings.json file

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am unable to read the few of the keys from `local.settings.json` file. Below is the file content.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "KeyVaultUrl": "https://mykeyvault.azure.net/",
    "SecretKey": "myconnectionstring",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

I used the below code to read these values

```
var keyVaultUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultUrl"); // returns null
var secretKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SecretKey"); // returns null
var sample = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"); // returns "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

I am not sure why it returns null for the key I have added. I have set `Copy Always` in `Copy to Output Directory` and `Build Action` to `None`.

Please assist.

Comment: This is because these value aren't "written" to the environment, you'll want to use the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) package to read the file into a `IConfiguration` object and then read the values from there

Comment: You seem to be confused about what an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) is. Your json values are configuration data as @MindSwipe explains.

Comment: What kind of project is this for? ASP.NET? Or a simple console app? Or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729997/how-to-avoid-hard-coding-urls/73731838#73731838

Answer (score 0):

An **environment variable** is a variable whose value is set outside the program, typically through functionality built into the **operating system**!

Your data in appsettings is just key-value pairs of configuration settings for your application (from it's name - **appsettings**).

To access data in your appsettings you need to inject **IConfiguration** to your service (or controller or whatever)

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public ServiceConstructor(public IConfiguration)
    => _configuration = configuration;
```

and then you can read values from there like this:

```
_configuration["IsEncrypted"]
```

and

```
_configuration["Values:KeyVaultUrl"]
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed information. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Values you are trying to read, are not written in environment variables. To use config files, use [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). It can contain environment variables, multiple config files and much more.

It depends on type of your application, if you are using simple console application without hosts and builders, use [this](https://pradeepl.com/blog/dotnet/configuration-in-a-net-core-console-application/), but if you are using some kind of framework use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) approach.